# Why won't my reduce function do anything?

Tags: c++

For a homework assignment, I'm making a program that accepts fractions from the user and then does different arithmetic operations with them. A side requirement is that it also has to reduce the answer before it displays it. We have to use a member function called reduce(). My problem is that when I call the reduce() function, it won't do anything. It's as if it just skips the statement and goes on to the next. Anybody know what's up?
Here's my member function definition for reduce():

```
void Rational::reduce()                                             
{
    if(num > denom)
    {
        int gcf = num;
        while(num % gcf != 0 || denom % gcf != 0)
        {
            gcf--;
        }
        num /= gcf;
        denom /= gcf;
    }
    else
    {
        int gcf = denom;
        while(num % gcf != 0 || denom % gcf != 0)
        {
            gcf--;
        }
        num /= gcf;
        denom /= gcf;
    }
}
```

Here is my overloaded + operator that calls reduce() but nothing happens. This is where the problem occurs. The normalize() function (changes a -n/-d fraction to n/d) works just fine but the reduce() function doesn't. Yet, the calls look exactly the same to me so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the function definitions.

```
Rational Rational::operator + (Rational f) const                 
{
    Rational temp;
    temp.num = (num * f.denom) + (denom * f.num);
    temp.denom = denom * f.denom;
    temp.normalize();
    temp.reduce();
    return Rational(temp);
}
```

Comment: So is your operator not getting called? Try putting some output in it temporarily, see if it's actually being used or not.

Comment: You can figure most of this out by stepping through your program in a debugger.

Comment: Your attempt to find the greatest common factor is wrong. It is not clear which approach you were trying to implement, whether euclid's algorithm, or by factoring, it's unclear. But, whichever approach you are trying to use here, it's wrong.

Comment: I know the + operator is called cuz normalize() is working fine. If I punch in a negative fraction it normalizes it but reduce() ain't doing nothin. And idk how to use a debugger 

Comment: And the method I'm using to reduce is my own method. Idk what you're talking about but I'm pretty sure it works

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. It is not Euclid or factoring. It just starts from the larger number and counts down to a common factor, which will be the greatest. I am a little worried  how it would behave though, if the numerator and denominator are opposite signs.

Comment: You're right to worry. You have to use absolute values of the numerator and the denominator, to compute the greatest common factor. Now, start your debugger, set a breakpoint on `Rational::reduce`, then either: 1) the breakpoint will be never hit, thus proving your theory that it never gets invoked, 2) the breakpoints get hit, and then you get to step through your code, one line at a time, determining its actual behavior, and how it differs from the expected behavior. This is called "debugging", a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Also, assuming num and denom are both positive, as an efficiency thing one could start the candidate gcf at the smaller of the numbers, not the larger as this method does (but that still will not explain why it fails; it would be interesting to know if it works on something like 6/3 for instance if you add 1/3 and 5/3).

Comment: Unless both `num` and `denom` are negative, your function should work, at least it seems to work for me with my limited tests. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, I see how by starting from the larger, if the signs are opposite, you are counting down from the positive number, which is good (saves you from counting down forever from the negative one).

Comment: what type are num and denom?